# Tikz /foreach problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, counters

The code below used to draw a plot of a permutation:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\normaldot}[1]{ % Make a dot of fixed absolute size.
    \node at #1 {\normalsize $\bullet$};
}

\newcommand{\plotperm}[1]{% plot a permutation
    \foreach \j [count=\i] in {#1} {
        \normaldot{(\i,\j)}{};
    };
}
\newcommand{\plotpermgrid}[1]{% plot a permutation in a grid
    \foreach \i [count=\n] in {#1} {};  % Now \n stores the number of entries of the permutation. 
    \foreach \i in {0,1,2,...,\n}{
        \draw [color=darkgray] ({\i+0.5}, 0.5)--({\i+0.5}, {\n+0.5});
        \draw [color=darkgray] (0.5, {\i+0.5})--({\n+0.5}, {\i+0.5});
    }
    \plotperm{#1};
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \plotpermgrid{2,4,1,3}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Using TexLive2017, this would result in a grid showing the points of the permutation (2,4,1,3) like this[image: plot of permutation 2413]

With TexLive2019, I get error messages, starting with "Undefined control sequence. \plotpermgrid{2,4,1,3}"

The problem appears to be related to the line

```
\foreach \i [count=\n] in {#1} {};
```

In TexLive2017, this sets `\n` to the number of elements of the permutation, and, critically, allows `\n` to be used after the `\foreach` has finished.  In TexLive2019, TexLine2020, and MikTex, `\n` is set within the loop, but cannot be used afterwards.

I could fix this by adding a second parameter for the number of elements, but this doesn't seem to be an elegant solution, and would be susceptible to errors.

I've tried using counters, but (with a counter called `gridsize`), I get errors when I write `\foreach \i in {0,1,2,...,{\thegridsize}}`.

I don't have the option to go back to TexLive2017, and I have a large number of LaTeX documents which use `\plotpermgrid` as defined above.

How can I change the definition of `\plotpermgrid` so that it works using TexLive2019 or later, while still taking a single parameter as before?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SE!

Actually the error you encountered was `undefined control sequence \n` (or words to that effect). `\n` is evaluated in `\foreach` which, in turn, is in a group. So, when the `\foreach` is finished, `\n` is forgotten. The trick is to make `\n` in effect global while the `\foreach` is running, as here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\normaldot}[1]{ % Make a dot of fixed absolute size.
    \node at #1 {\normalsize $\bullet$};
}

\newcommand{\plotperm}[1]{% plot a permutation
    \foreach \j [count=\i] in {#1} {
        \normaldot{(\i,\j)}{};
    };
}
\newcommand{\plotpermgrid}[1]{% plot a permutation in a grid
    \foreach \i [count=\n] in {#1} {\global\let\newn=\n};  % Now \newn stores the number of entries of the permutation globally. <<<--- 
    \foreach \i in {0,1,2,...,\newn}{
        \draw [color=darkgray] ({\i+0.5}, 0.5)--({\i+0.5}, {\newn+0.5});
        \draw [color=darkgray] (0.5, {\i+0.5})--({\newn+0.5}, {\i+0.5});
    }
    \plotperm{#1};
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \plotpermgrid{2,4,1,3}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The graphic produced is precisely what you posted.

Answer (score 3):

You should instead compute the length of the input array:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\normaldot}[1]{ % Make a dot of fixed absolute size.
    \node at #1 {\normalsize $\bullet$};
}

\newcommand{\plotperm}[1]{% plot a permutation
    \foreach \j [count=\i] in {#1} {
        \normaldot{(\i,\j)}{};
    };
}
\newcommand{\plotpermgrid}[1]{% plot a permutation in a grid
    \pgfmathsetmacro\n{dim({#1})}% compute the length of the array
    \foreach \i in {0,1,...,\n}{
        \draw [color=darkgray] ({\i+0.5}, 0.5)--({\i+0.5}, {\n+0.5});
        \draw [color=darkgray] (0.5, {\i+0.5})--({\n+0.5}, {\i+0.5});
    }
    \plotperm{#1};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \plotpermgrid{2,4,1,3}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Using `{#1}` transforms the argument in a properly delimited PGF array. The method has worked since TeX Live 2013 (Ti*k*Z/PGF version 3.0.0).

I believe that leaving `\n` defined after `\foreach \i [count=\n] in {...}{...}` has been deemed a bug and fixed, because all temporary control sequences used in a `\foreach` loop should be local to the loop and not leave anything outside it (unless made global).

---

Having been informed (in a very unpleasant way, to be honest) that `dim` doesn't always behave as expected, although in your situation it should, provided the argument to `\plotpermgrid` has at least two items, I provide a safer solution.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse} % not needed with LaTeX release 2020-10-01 or later

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\clistlen}{m}
 {
  \clist_count:n { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\newcommand{\normaldot}[1]{ % Make a dot of fixed absolute size.
    \node at #1 {\normalsize $\bullet$};
}

\newcommand{\plotperm}[1]{% plot a permutation
    \foreach \j [count=\i] in {#1} {
        \normaldot{(\i,\j)}{};
    };
}
\newcommand{\plotpermgrid}[1]{% plot a permutation in a grid
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\n}{\clistlen{#1}}% get the number of items in #1
    \foreach \i in {0,1,...,\n}{
        \draw [color=darkgray] ({\i+0.5}, 0.5)--({\i+0.5}, {\n+0.5});
        \draw [color=darkgray] (0.5, {\i+0.5})--({\n+0.5}, {\i+0.5});
    }
    \plotperm{#1};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \plotpermgrid{2,4,1,3}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

You can even avoid to define `\n` and use `\clistlen{#1}` where `\n` is used.

Comment: Where can I read about `clistlen`? -Google and TikZ manual does not help.

Comment: @hpekristiansen It's defined it *ad hoc* in the code I wrote. It uses `expl3` features.

Comment: Thanks - I see it now. A shame that non-readable by mortals expl3 is needed.

Comment: @hpekristiansen The function `\clist_count:n` returns the number of items in its argument, which is supposed to be a comma separated list.

Answer (score 2):

A wee bit different approach. Defined is only one new command which can be used in text, grid is drawn as nodes, no global sewing dimension of grid:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
                         
\newcommand{\PPG}[1]% Plot a Permutation in a Grid
{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[nodes={minimum size=1cm}]
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {#1} %\i: columns, \j: rows
{
\node at (\j-0.5,\i-0.5) {\textbullet};
    \foreach \k in {1,...,\j}
    {
    \node[draw] at (\j-0.5,\k-0.5) {};
    \node[draw] at (\k-0.5,\j-0.5) {};
    }
}
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\PPG{2,4,1,3,5}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\PPG{2,4,1,3,5}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum.**
If plot of termination in a grid (`\PPG`) is always used in `tikzpicture` environment, for example:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\PPG{2,4,1,3,5}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

then may be better that `tikzpicture` is removed from definition of `\PPG`:

```
\newcommand{\PPG}[1]% Plot a Permutation in a Grid
{
    \scoped[nodes={minimum size=1cm}]{
\foreach \i [count=\j] in {#1} %\i: columns, \j: rows
{
\node at (\j-0.5,\i-0.5) {\textbullet};
    \foreach \k in {1,...,\j}
    {
    \node[draw] at (\j-0.5,\k-0.5) {};
    \node[draw] at (\k-0.5,\j-0.5) {};
    }
}% end of foreach
                                    }% end  of scoped
}% end of newcommand
```